# CodeIgniter 3 - Reload View with Different CSS Theme

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm still trying to wrap my head around the relationship between controller functions and URL requests.

**This is what I'm trying to accomplish:**

I've got a single view containing a full HTML page (no templates). On this page I want users to be able to select a theme from a list of links. Each theme has a separate CSS file. I would like the selected link to pass a value to the controller which then reloads the same view with a different CSS file using the $data array.

If the scenario I described above is possible, or if there is a smarter solution, then I'd greatly appreciate any help or suggestions.

**Basic View/Controller Structure:**

*I've marked everything I don't understand with ?????????*

controllers/Demos.php

```
public function ?????????
{
    $data['theme'] = array(
        'Normal' => "normal.css",
        'Dark' => "dark.css",
        'Light' => "light.css",
        'Ultraviolet' => "ultraviolet.css"
    );

    $this->load->view('demos/themeswap', $data);
```

views/demos/themeswap.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Theme Swap Demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/<?php echo $theme ?>.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Theme Swap Demo</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="?????????">Standard</a></li>
                <li><a href="?????????">Dark</a></li>
                <li><a href="?????????">Light</a></li>
                <li><a href="?????????">Ultraviolet</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
<main>
    <h1>Some Rock-Solid Content</h1>
    <p>Behold! I am a paragraph!</p>
</main>
<footer>
    <p>What an amazing footer.</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first ?????? (method name) should look like this:

```
public function theme($theme)
```

Then, or your themeswap.php view:

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('demos/theme/standard'); ?>">Standard</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('demos/theme/dark'); ?>">Dark</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('demos/theme/light'); ?>">Light</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('demos/theme/ultraviolet'); ?>">Ultraviolet</a></li>
        </ul>
```

On your URL structure you will usually have `controller/method/variables` if configured to remove index.php and not defining custom routes.

More info about this [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

Comment: I suggest using `base_url()` as it was designed to be used. e.g.  `<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('/demos/theme/standard'); ?>">Standard</a></li>`

Comment: @zJorge After many attempts and further research, I actually wasn't able to get this working. I need to be able to set the default css file to standard.css, and then replace it with another method. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: I just prepared a quick example at http://bdmercado.avance.com.pa/demos/theme/ for you. I didn't go all the way to load a CSS file but instead just changed the background color.  Please take a look.

Comment: Now it loads the CSS if there is one with the name.  If not it goes 404 for the CSS but if the name is actually a valid CSS color name (ie, whitesmoke or blanchedalmond) it will be used as body background. Try it!

Comment: @zJorge I'd need to see the controller code for your example to get an idea of why mine isn't working, but don't bother because I created a new posting for this issue with far more detail. Please have a look and see if you can figure it out with the new info: [New Post].(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124375/codeigniter-3-x-reload-view-with-different-css-file-using-user-input/44124501#44124501) Your method must work properly from what I can see in your example, so your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Why you do not try it with jquery, it is very easy and reliable then redirecting using the anchor tag.

```
<ul class="change_theme">
    <li data-theme="Standard">Standard</li>
    <li data-theme="Dark">Dark</li>
    <li data-theme="Light">Light</li>
    <li data-theme="Ultraviolet">Ultraviolet</li>
</ul>
```

Design theme like if you change one class in body tag change will be applied in entire page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var current_theme = "Standard";
              $('.change_theme [data-theme]').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var new_theme = $(this).data('theme');
                $('body').removeClass(current_theme);
                $('body').addClass(new_theme);
                current_theme = new_theme;
              });
        });

    </script>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/h9mapnsp/2/) on Fiddle