# CodeIgniter 3.x - Reload View with Different CSS File Using User Input

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**Problem:**

I created a static page view (in its own view folder) that demos the new Sakura.css framework. The framework comes with four CSS themes. I want to be able to select a theme from a list of links and reload the same view with the associated CSS theme file via the controller. *I also need the view to default to the 'standard.css' theme.* Finally, I'd like to avoid JavaScript/jQuery solutions.

I'm struggling to grasp the relationship between controller function names, custom routing, and the URI. I think I'm at the brink of an 'aha' moment, and finding a solution this issue out is definitely going to help.

**Current Code:**

*Note: I've also set .htaccess to remove index.php from the URL.*

views/sakura/index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sakura Demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset_url() ;?>css/<?php echo $theme; ?>.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a <?php if (isset($theme) && ($theme = 'standard')) { echo 'class="current"'; } ?>href="<?php echo base_url('sakura/standard'); ?>">Standard</a></li>
            <li><a <?php if (isset($theme) && ($theme = 'dark')) { echo 'class="current"'; } ?>href="<?php echo base_url('sakura/dark'); ?>">Dark</a></li>
            <li><a <?php if (isset($theme) && ($theme = 'earthly')) { echo 'class="current"'; } ?>href="<?php echo base_url('sakura/earthly'); ?>">Earthly</a></li>
            <li><a <?php if (isset($theme) && ($theme = 'vader')) { echo 'class="current"'; } ?>href="<?php echo base_url('sakura/vader'); ?>">Vader</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<main>
    <h1>Sakura.css Demo</h1>
    <p>Sakura.css is a minimal css framework/theme that can be dropped into any project for an instantaneous modern-looking website.</p>
</main>

<footer>
    <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

controllers/Sakura.php

```
<?php
class Sakura extends CI_Controller {

    public function theme($theme)
    {
        $data['theme'] = array(
            'standard' => "standard",
            'dark' => "dark",
            'earthly' => "earthly",
            'vader' => "vader"
        );

        $this->load->view('sakura/theme', $data);
    }
}
```

config/routes.php

```
<?php
$route['sakura/(:any)'] = 'sakura/$1';
$route['sakura'] = 'sakura';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

The only way I've been able to get the view to load at all is with this function in the Sakura.php controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['theme'] = "standard";

    $this->load->view('sakura/index', $data);
}
```

**Desired URL Structure:** <-- Not necessary, but would be great!

Default View: mywebsite.com/sakura/ **-or-** mywebsite.com/sakura/standard

Theme View: mywebsite.com/sakura/selected-theme

**Final Thoughts:**

Thank you all in advance for any help on this issue. I rely on the StackOverflow community often and I greatly appreciate the time and consideration that goes into solving my issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but try something like...?

Controller

```
$css = $this->uri->segment(2);
$allowed_input = array('standard', 'dark', 'earthly', 'vader');
if ((isset($css)) && (!in_array($css, $allowed_input))) {
    echo 'Filthy human!';
}

$data['css'] = $css; // You can probably just do this above, it's just harder to type.
```

View

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset_url() ;?>css/<?php echo (!isset($css) ? 'standard' : $css);?>.css" media="screen" />
```

Route

Change the first line to:

```
$route['sakura/(:any)'] = 'sakura/index/$1';
```

Then mywebsite.com/sakura/standard should work, but if the "standard" bit isn't there, it'll load the standard by default. Threw in the in_array() bit as a small sanity check, but you'll probably want to be more thorough in your validation.

Comment: It's not working, but I also don't know if I'm supposed to be putting this in the index() method. The page loads, but the $css variable isn't set, nor does it default to standard.

Comment: The controller code would go in the index() method. Also, since you're hiding the index, the URI segment may be 1 instead of 2? If you echo $css directly from the controller, does it give any additional information?

Comment: echoing the $css variable has no impact on the loaded view. When I click any of the theme links, I get a 404. The URI structure reads sakura/theme so that seems to be working properly.

Comment: I didn't mean it should have an impact on the loaded view, I was just curious as to whether it was even being set in the controller. Are you loading the uri helper? ($this->load->helper('uri'))

Comment: Nope, thought I autoloaded it. I now have it autoloading, but all theme links except vader return a 404, and the css doesn't load. You were right the first time, the segment needs to be 2. Echoing $css now echoes the theme name. How bizarre.

Comment: The route config was updated. Is your php function in your link example the proper syntax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144883/discussion-between-tyler-f-and-joe).

Comment: I forgot the echo before the ternary in the view code. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to deal with routes to achieve it. This is how I would solve it:

**Controller (Sakura.php)**

```
class Sakura extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function theme($theme='standard') {
        $data['theme']=$theme;
        $data['main_content'] = 'sakura/sakura_view';
        $this -> load -> view('sakura/sakura_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Notice that I used `public function theme($theme='standard')` so it defaults to standard if there is no a parameter defined on the third URI segment.

**View (views/sakura/sakura_view.php)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sakura Demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset_url() ;?>css/<?php echo $theme; ?>.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a <?php if (isset($theme) && ($theme = 'standard')) { echo 'class="current"'; } ?>href="<?php echo base_url('sakura/standard'); ?>">Standard</a></li>
            <li><a <?php if (isset($theme) && ($theme = 'dark')) { echo 'class="current"'; } ?>href="<?php echo base_url('sakura/dark'); ?>">Dark</a></li>
            <li><a <?php if (isset($theme) && ($theme = 'earthly')) { echo 'class="current"'; } ?>href="<?php echo base_url('sakura/earthly'); ?>">Earthly</a></li>
            <li><a <?php if (isset($theme) && ($theme = 'vader')) { echo 'class="current"'; } ?>href="<?php echo base_url('sakura/vader'); ?>">Vader</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<main>
    <h1>Sakura.css Demo</h1>
    <p>Sakura.css is a minimal css framework/theme that can be dropped into any project for an instantaneous modern-looking website.</p>
</main>

<footer>
    <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```